# Creating shcedules in a for loop with varying parameters in python

Tags: python, scheduling

The script below should set up scheduling at two specified times while passing individual parameters to each run. In this case the output should be `1` and `2`, however the output is `2` and `2`, somehow passing only the last variable to the parameters.

```
import schedule, threading, time


def run_script(n):
    #Check this output
    print(n)

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()


times = ["13:56", "13:56"]

for n,row in enumerate(times, 1):
    schedule.every().day.at(row).do(run_threaded, lambda: run_script(n))


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you run the script without the loop manually like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("18:56").do(run_threaded, lambda: run_script(1))
schedule.every().day.at("18:56").do(run_threaded, lambda: run_script(2))
```

This works fine! However when generated by the loop the result is not the same.

Does anyone have any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: just tested your code and it seems fine. other than you forgot to `import time` my output is
`13:56  1  | 13:56  2`

Comment: I think you need to check the output of `run_script(n)` where `n` is the output when run at those specified times. I am still getting `2` `2`